# Issues calculating Height ExpandableListView

Tags: android, listview, height, expandablelistview

I'm trying to calculate the height of an expandable list view so i can show all the items incluing the headers so the user wont have to scroll to see the content.

This is the fragment where i show the listview. Next to it is a calendar:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".fragments.DashboardFragment">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".fragments.DashboardFragment">
        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/lvExp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <CalendarView
            android:id="@+id/calendarView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="292dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm calculating the height in the setOnGroupExpandListener located on the fragment. First of all i get the height of two children for the headers:

```
height += ((expListView.getChildAt(0).getHeight()+expListView.getDividerHeight())-expListView.getDividerHeight())*listAdapter.getGroupCount();
```

Then i calculate the height of the children using the next formula:

```
for (int i = 0; i <  listAdapter.getGroupCount();i++){
if (expListView.isGroupExpanded(i)){        
    height += listAdapter.getChildrenCount(i)*(expListView.getChildAt(0).getHeight()+expListView.getDividerHeight())-expListView.getDividerHeight();        
}
}
```

When i expand the first group a gap is placed between the listview and the calendar. When i expand the second group, a bigger gap is placed between them.

I've got the same formula to collapse them.

Should i use another formula to calculate the height?

[image: All items collapsed]

[image: First item expanded]

[image: All items expanded]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing this at all.  The point of a listview is to scroll.  If you don't want it to scroll, just add it as views to a LinearLayout.

As for your algorithm-  it won't work.  A ListView doesn't know the heights of any of its items unless they're currently onscreen.  So its actually not possible to calculate this.

Also, what you're doing wouldn't calculate the heights of all views-  listviews only have children for items that are onscreen.  They recycle items between those.  So your algorithm would only get the height of the items currently onscreen.

Comment: the problem is that i need to show a list of items and it must expand/collapse and the only solution that i've found was using the expandable listview. If you know another solution i'll be very grateful

Comment: Expandable listview is good for that-  so long as you want (or at least don't mind) scrolling.  If you don't want scrolling, then you do not want to use any form of a listview.  At that point its time to write a view of your own.  Although looking at your example-  I think scrolling is entirely appropriate.